# grid_pipeline.fit uses default value of solver parameter instead of GridSearchCV value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I tried to find the best combination of hyperparameters for `LogisticRegression` in `sklearn`. Below is the example of my code:

```py
pipeline = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler()),
                     ("smt",    SMOTE(random_state=42)),
                     ("logreg", LogisticRegression())])


parameters = [{'logreg__solver': ['saga']},
              {'logreg__penalty':['l1', 'l2']},
              {'logreg__C':[1e-3, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}]

grid_pipeline = GridSearchCV(pipeline,
                             parameters, 
                             scoring= 'f1', 
                             n_jobs=5, verbose=5,
                             return_train_score=True, 
                             cv=5) 

grid_result = grid_pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

During fitting I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty.
```

For some reason, default value 'lbfgs' is used for `solver` parameter instead of chosen 'saga'. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is how you have specified `parameters`. To get the desired behaviour, use a single `dict` as follows:

```
parameters = {'logreg__solver': ['saga'],
              'logreg__penalty':['l1', 'l2'],
              'logreg__C':[1e-3, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
              }
```

You had specified it as a list of dicts, which gave `GridSearchCV` the option of picking some and ignoring others, meaning it sometimes encountered the request to use `l1` on the default (non-`saga`) solver. Those two options are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing your parameters as a list of dictionaries, instead of a dictionary of lists?

Isn't

```py
parameters = {'solver': ['saga'],
              'penalty':[ 'l1', 'l2'],
              'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}
```

what you want?

Works here.

Comment: Truth is, according to the docs, it can be either a dict or a list of dictionaries: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: Yeah I understand both are possible and cater for different use cases (not all combinations are possible in a list of dict case). But here, list of dict does not seem like the wanted usage, hence I started by asking the question